# Regex Extract SQL

Tags: sql, regex

I have a string in one of my columns that looks like this:

DadC - Review Vid - Vid - Eng - TC

How can I regex extract using SQL the second to last word 'Eng'?
How can I regex extract the second-word 'Review Vid"?

Currently in google SQL I have a query that looks like this to extract the last word:
SELECT *,
REGEX_EXTRACT(column_name, r'(\w+$)') AS lan

Comment: does `SELECT *, REGEX_EXTRACT(column_name, r'(\w+) - \w+$')` work?

Comment: YES! By any chance do you have a source that I can look at for regex?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say _"google SQL..."_?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10496674

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression `(\w+$)` contains the following bits:

- `(...)` capture the stuff inside
- `\w`    a word character: letters and numbers and underscore
- `+`     at least one of the previous thing
- `$`     the end of the text

So `\w+` means "at least one word character"
And `\w+$` means "at least one word character at the end of the text"
And `(\w+$)` means "capture at least one word character at the end of the text"

But you don't want to capture those word characters - you want something earlier in the text.

So `\w+ - \w+` would match two words with a dash between.
And `\w+ - \w+$` would match two words with a dash between at the end of the text.

And all that is left is to put parens around the part you want to capture: `(\w+) - \w+$`